# How to integrate by parts and $u$-sub $8 \ln(\sqrt[3]{x})$?

Tags: integration

I am having trouble integrating the following equation by first using u-sub and then integration by parts:

$$\int 8 \ln{\sqrt[3]{x}}~dx$$

I looked up the answer on Wolfram Alpha but it is still unclear to me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi. Can you show a bit of your work on this so far? This way it is easier to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Remember that $\log(x^a)=a \log(x)$. So $$\int 8 \ln{\sqrt[3]{x}}~dx=\frac{8}{3} \int \log(x)~dx$$ Now, use integration by parts.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: You saved my life!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you! Thank you both!

Comment: I did not save your life and you are very welcome !

Answer (score 0):

Call it $\frac{8}{3}\ln x$, and let $u=\ln x$, $dv=\frac{8}{3}\,dx$.

But you can actually integrate directly by parts, $u=8\ln(x^{1/3})$, $dv=dx$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!! It helped me a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. In this case, we don't need to bother with substitution, though it is a natural and often useful idea.